# Json data reading in client side in asp.net application

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following data as json:

```
 "Table":[
 {
 "AF":2000.00
 "RegionNumber":1
 "RegionName":"Black Sea"
 },
 {
 "AF":100.00
 "RegionNumber":1
 "RegionName":"Black Sea"
 },
 {
 "AF":15000.00
 "RegionNumber":2
 "RegionName":"Istanbul"
 },
 {
 "AF":31000.00
 "RegionNumber":1
 "RegionName":"Black Sea"
 },
 {
 "AF":11000.00
 "RegionNumber":2
 "RegionName":"Istanbul"
 }
 ]
```

I want to arrange the data in the following format in Javascript.

```
series: [{
    name: 'Black Sea',
    data: [2000, 100, 31000],
    stack: 'Bookings'
}, {
    name: 'Istanbul',
    data: [15000,11000,0],
    stack: 'Bookings'
}]
```

How can I accomplish this transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This almost does what you ask and uses Ramda.js too

```js
const data =  {
    Table: [
        {
            AF: 2000,
            RegionName: "Black Sea",
            RegionNumber: 1
        },
        {
            AF: 100,
            RegionName: "Black Sea",
            RegionNumber: 1
        },
        {
            AF: 15000,
            RegionName: "Istanbul",
            RegionNumber: 2
        },
        {
            AF: 31000,
            RegionName: "Black Sea",
            RegionNumber: 1
        },
        {
            AF: 11000,
            RegionName: "Istanbul",
            RegionNumber: 2
        }
    ]
}

const transfromTableData =
  R.pipe(
    R.groupBy(R.prop("RegionName")),
    R.map(R.pluck("AF")),
    R.toPairs,
    R.map(R.zipObj(["name", "data"])) 
  )

const transfromData = (data) => ({
  series: transfromTableData(data.Table)
})

console.log(transfromData(data))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure JavaScript:

```
 var memo = {}
 for (var i in table) {
     var item = table[i];
     if (memo[item.RegionName] !== undefined) memo[item.RegionName].data.push(item.AF);
     else memo[item.RegionName] = {
         name: item.RegionName,
         data: [item.AF],
         stack: 'Bookings'
     }
 }

 var result = {
     series: []
 };

 for (var i in memo) {
     result.series.push(memo[i]);
 }

 console.log(result);
```

Comment: hi sza.. i am getting the data..how to include these result in Heighchat series

Answer (score 0):

I'm passing arrays of custom objects into List in web methods and it works just fine.

I'm, guessing that you're having a small JSON formatting issue because of the quotes around the property names. Try changing your object to this :

```
var scoresList = [{TraitID:1, TraitScore:2}, {TraitID:2, TraitScore:5}];
```

and change your data line to this :

```
data: JSON.stringify({ scores : scoresList }),
```

Hope that helps...

UPDATE: working example...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

    var scoresList = [{ TraitID: 1, TraitScore: 2 }, { TraitID: 2, TraitScore: 5}];

    $.ajax({ type: "POST",
        url: "Tryouts.aspx/Test",
        data: JSON.stringify({ scores: scoresList }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.d == true) {
                alert("success!!!!!");
            } else {
                alert("problem!!!!!!!!!");
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert("ERROR");
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Here's the codebehind :

```
public class Score
{    // default constructor    
    public Score() { }
    public int TraitID { get; set; }
    public double TraitScore { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod]
public static bool Test( List<Score> scores )
{
    return true;
}
```